# close pop-up and refresh website

Tags: jquery

Do you know how should I write correct method click?

JS - here I made mistake

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").live("click", function (e) {
    window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 100);
});
```

There is class with button

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 100);
});
```

Comment: I will accept your Answer when I delete this e.preventDefalut(); working correct thanks

Comment: Thanks for help I have to wait 1 minute to accept your post :)